# Add gender column recognization

Tags: r

```
demo_df <- data_frame(id = c(1,2,3), names = c("Hillary", "Madison", "John"), stock = c(43,5,2), bill = c(43,112,33))
```

How is it possible to use in names column the gender identification?
Expected output:

```
demo_df <- data_frame(id = c(1,2,3), names = c("Hillary", "Madison", "John"), gender = c("female", "female", "male"), stock = c(43,5,2), bill = c(43,112,33))
```

Tried this

```
library(gender)
test <- gender_df(demo_df, method = "demo",
           name_col = "name", year_col = c("1900", "2000"))
```

but I receive this error

> ```
> Error in gender_df(demo_df, method = "demo", name_col = "name") : 
>   year_col %in% names(data) is not TRUE
> ```

Comment: In the `demo_df`, there is no `year_col` and `name_col = "names"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `gender()` instead of `gender_df()`.

Note that `gender()` automatically sorts output alphabetically by name, so it won't work to simply add the output as a new vector to `demo_df`, as the ordering may be wrong.

Two options to handle this:
1. Sort `demo_df` alphabetically by name before you call  `gender()`.

```
library(dplyr)

demo_df %>% 
  arrange(names) %>%
  mutate(gender = gender::gender(demo_df$names)$gender)
```

2. Use a `join` method, like `dplyr::inner_join`, to merge `demo_df` and the resulting data frame output of the call to `gender()`, on the `names` column.

```
gender_df <- gender::gender(demo_df$names) %>% 
  select(names = name, gender)

inner_join(demo_df, gender_df, by = "names")
```

Output:

```
  id   names stock bill gender
1  1 Hillary    43   43 female
2  2 Madison     5  112 female
3  3    John     2   33   male
```

All of this is possible in base R, too, not including the gender imputation part.  I just prefer `dplyr`.

Comment: It seems very logical but any idea why I receive this in my full dataset `Error: Column `gender` must be length 51271 (the number of rows) or one, not 4763`

Comment: you matched 4763 names out of 51271 rows.  this may be because some names were not found in the lookup table used by `gender`.  it also may be that there are duplicate names in your data.  but `gender()` only  returns one row per unique name/year combo.  (or in the case no years are provided, one row per name.)  in the case of duplicate names, the join approach is better as it won't run into the row mismatch issue.

Comment: note that you'll probably want `left_join` instead of `inner_join` for `left_join(demo_df, gender_df, by = "names")` to retain all the rows in your actual dataframe.